# Multiple viewholder in RecyclerView skips items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have an adapter which is responsible to read from my local database and display some cardviews, yesterday I added another view in to the mix to handle the admob advertisements. but where it adds an add. it skips one of my database entries.

so what I did was this

```
int TYPE_POST = 0;
int TYPE_AD = 1;
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if ((position % 5) == 0) {
            return TYPE_AD;
        }

        return  TYPE_POST;
    }
```

and I have this onBindViewHolder if i change this  `final dbFeed dbfeed = LemesosAdapter.get(position);` to  `final dbFeed dbfeed = LemesosAdapter.get(position+1);`  the very 1st post wont be skipped . but the second time an advert is added it will be skipped.

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if (getItemViewType(position) == TYPE_POST) {
        // - get element from dataset at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element
        PostViewHolder postViewHolder = (PostViewHolder)holder;
        final dbFeed dbfeed = LemesosAdapter.get(position);
        //Animation by yoyo library
        YoYo.with(Techniques.BounceIn).playOn(postViewHolder.cardView);
        String description;

        description = Html.fromHtml(dbfeed.getDescription()).toString().replaceAll("\n", "").trim().substring(0, 100).replace((char) 65532, (char) 32).trim() + "...";
        postViewHolder.Title.setText(dbfeed.getTitle());
        postViewHolder.Description.setText(description);
        postViewHolder.Date.setText(dbfeed.getPubDate());
        Picasso.with(context).load(dbfeed.getThumbnailUrl()).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_image).into(postViewHolder.Thumbnail);
        postViewHolder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, NewsDetails.class);
                intent.putExtra("ThumbNail", dbfeed.getThumbnailUrl());
                intent.putExtra("Link", dbfeed.getThumbnailUrl());
                intent.putExtra("Title", dbfeed.getTitle());
                intent.putExtra("Description", dbfeed.getDescription());
                intent.putExtra("Date", dbfeed.getPubDate());
                context.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });


    } else if (getItemViewType(position) == TYPE_AD ) {


    }

}
```

and finally my getItemCount . in here I think is where the solution is. ive seen in this side in other post that I should do the same Modal as I did with my starting one ((itemcount %5) + itemcount) but it does not work

```
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return ((LemesosAdapter.size()%5))+LemesosAdapter.size() ;
    }
}
```

what I am missing here?

Comment: Can you please set item count like below.
`@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (((int) LemesosAdapter.size()/5))+LemesosAdapter.size() ;
    }`

Comment: OMG, I'm not see that %. I see it as /.

Comment: @MahavirJain this still skips each 5th position as well

Comment: Also you have to change logic.
`LemesosAdapter.get(getPosition(position))
fun getPosition(position: Int): Int = (position + (position / 5))`

Comment: @MahavirJain what is fun stands for? is it kotlin ?

Comment: Yes, fun is keyword in kotlin to declare any function. @Demeteor

Comment: ok how would that translate into non kotlin?  the answer I accepted turns out to be wrong. I get outofbounts if I scroll back up. and trying to find out a way to fix this.
even If I make my getitemcount()  to return 36 by doing the thing you suggested .
return  return ((LemesosAdapter.size() + (LemesosAdapter.size()/5)));  

I still get thrown an out of bounds. so I my ques here is not to do any operations within    final dbFeed dbfeed = LemesosAdapter.get(position);

I think I might be close but I cant solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see, every time ads show up it will skip one of your item because both post and ads share the same position. You can check by Log outside of these if-else condition.

```
if (getItemViewType(position) == TYPE_POST) {
    // - get element from dataset at this position
    // - replace the contents of the view with that element
    PostViewHolder postViewHolder = (PostViewHolder)holder;
    final dbFeed dbfeed = LemesosAdapter.get(position - count);
    //Animation by yoyo library
    YoYo.with(Techniques.BounceIn).playOn(postViewHolder.cardView);
    String description;

    description = Html.fromHtml(dbfeed.getDescription()).toString().replaceAll("\n", "").trim().substring(0, 100).replace((char) 65532, (char) 32).trim() + "...";
    postViewHolder.Title.setText(dbfeed.getTitle());
    postViewHolder.Description.setText(description);
    postViewHolder.Date.setText(dbfeed.getPubDate());
    Picasso.with(context).load(dbfeed.getThumbnailUrl()).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_image).into(postViewHolder.Thumbnail);
    postViewHolder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, NewsDetails.class);
            intent.putExtra("ThumbNail", dbfeed.getThumbnailUrl());
            intent.putExtra("Link", dbfeed.getThumbnailUrl());
            intent.putExtra("Title", dbfeed.getTitle());
            intent.putExtra("Description", dbfeed.getDescription());
            intent.putExtra("Date", dbfeed.getPubDate());
            context.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });


} else if (getItemViewType(position) == TYPE_AD ) {
    count += 1
}
```

Comment: Yeah I understand why is happening, but I dont know how I can solve this without breaking the entire thing

Comment: If you have 2 set of data, I think you need some variable to count every time ads show up. Then use that count to decrease position in item of Type_post.

Comment: Yes as I am trying to do. here (LemesosAdapter.size()%5))+LemesosAdapter.size()  this will add back to the count as far as ive seen in other post. the problem is that I cant figure out how to actually make it work. thanks for trying though

Comment: what was changed here? count +=1 ?  basically you want me to add an element back each time I use type_ad?

Comment: That worked like a charm,  I declaired as you said a variable and did what you showed me, now it works. sometimes I guess there are simple solutions no needing more complicated math. thanks